# how to validate or detect the addtional request parameter in graph-ql java?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

We are using Graph-QL Java for our GraphQL server.
our use case is to verify additional query parameter and throw error

**Mutation request:**

```
mutation{actionHandler(action:"status",entity:"integration",ids:[1],value:"Run"){result}} OR 1=1
```

**Schema class:**

```
public class ActionHandler {
    private String entity;
    private String action;
    private String value;
    private List<Integer> ids;
    private List<String> result;
}
```

Above query having the additional request parameter OR 1=1. these are not part of defined schema. note this been given to verify the vulnerability attack using boolean condition.

above query gives exactly the same results as the actual schema request gives

**Expected/Actual schema request:**
     mutation{actionHandler(action:"status",entity:"integration",ids:[1],value:"Run"){result}}

injected additional boolean condition (OR 1=1 ) as parameter does not manipulating the query results. it seems to be those been ignored when graph ql native parser convert mutation query to corresponding schema object.

how we can verify additional input parameter  using GraphQL native lib itself which are not part of schema request?